# problem with IE

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

my client is saying that she couldn't register on our website and getting error
When she was registering, she would enter all the information, and when she would click through, an error message would tell her that the name field only allowed letters and not numbers.  She wasn't entering any numbers.

Could this be a problem with her browser?  (She is using Internet Explorer.)  Her computer?  What else could it be?
I tried it, and it worked for me.

i am using regular expression

```
ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z]+$".
```

Comment: What exactly did she imputed? It could be a character that is not in the "a-z" range (č,š,ž,č,đ,...)

Comment: When you say you tried it, did you type exactly what she says she typed, or just something you think is reasonable?

Comment: Yes, using IE is an error on her part.

Answer (score 2):

She might not be entering numbers, but is that all your error message states?

She might be entering punctuation, symbols, or spaces.

Copying and pasting something in could also leave a trailing space which would fail your validation.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps her name has a hyphen, apostrophe or accented character in it. If it is a full name, then it is probably erroring on the space between the forename and surname!

Avoid restricting what users are allowed to input as you'll usually end up stopping people from entering things that *should* be perfectly acceptable, just use suitable escape sequences (e.g. with paramertised queries for databases or converting `<`, `>`, `&`, `"` and `'` to their respective entities for HTML) before putting the data anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not a technical person.  The chances are that the name entered has and apostrophe, space, or anything that isn't between a-z.

The reason you are getting this message is because whoever created the system has told is to say that when the name doesn't match the regular expression, even though it probably has nothing to do with entering a number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  I'll say it a thousand times.  Never assume what the end user is saying is true or what they claim to be doing is what they actually are doing.   Not that they are deceitful, just they often don't know.

I recommend using a remote desktop software such as Co-Pilot  (no, I don't work for fogcreek) and connecting to any user that can replicate this issue and view it happening for yourself.

Once you can verify it is indeed happening, you should be able to replicate it from your end and then submit it to the developers (or yourself) to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

I'ts not a browser-related problem. ASP.NET form validation is server-side.